# Preferable design pattern for model with background networking

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

I'm developing a model class that provides data parsed from the web. Of course, I'd like my application to be responsive and thus networking should be done on separate thread/queue.

That leads to the question: *how should I design the @interface of my class*?

The main requirements are:

- It should deliver data from Model to Viewcontroller :) ;
- It shouldn't block the main (UI) thread;
- It should be easy to understand and follow by other developers.

From what I've learned from WWDC2012 video, "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS" Apple recommends to move the concurrent code to the class itself that uses model.

Let's say we have Posts class (Posts.h/.m) that should provide ViewController with latest posts in NSArray* format.

**Option I -- concurrency is in class users**

The class itself is not concurrent, but the users are:

```
//Posts.h:
@interface Posts : NSObject

- (NSArray*)getPostsForUser:(NSString*)user;

@end


//ViewController.m
@implementation ViewController

- (void)someFunctionThatUpdatesUI
{
    //<...>
    NSOperationQueue *q = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [q addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSArray *currentPosts = [Posts shared] getPostsForUser:@"mike";
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    //UI should be updated only on main thread
            [self updateUIWithPosts:currentPosts]; 
        }];
    }];
    //<...>
}
```

The main disadvantage of this approach is the necessity to repeat almost the same code in every ViewController. What if there are dozens of them?

**Option II -- concurrency with completion handlers pattern**

Second option that I currently use in my app is a completion handler pattern. As the completion handler is called only *after* some long networking is performed, it doesn't block the main thread:

```
//Posts.h:
@interface Posts : NSObject

- (NSError*)getPostsForUser:(NSString*)user 
    withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSArray*))handler;

@end

@implementation Posts

- (NSError*)getPostsForUser:(NSString*)user 
    withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSArray*))handler
{
    //<...>
    dispatch_async(dipatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        //Do some may-be-long networking stuff here, 
        //parse, etc and put it into NSArray *result
        dispatch_async(dipatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            handler(result);
        });
    });
    //<...>
}

//ViewController.m
- (void)someFunctionThatUpdatesUI
{
    //<...>
    [Posts shared] getPostsForUser:@"mike" 
         withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray* posts){
        //updateUI with posts
    }];
}
```

From my point of view, this way is good but the @interface is rather complicated, the method names are long and (from my point of view) obfuscated.

**Option III -- delegate pattern**

Another option that I see is the delegate pattern. What bothers me is that only one ViewController may be the delegate, thus it leads to necessity to set every VC as delegate in - viewWillAppear, which is easy to forget.

```
//Posts.h:
@protocol PostUpdate<NSObject>

- (void)updateUIWithPosts:(NSArray*)posts FromUser:(NSString*)user;

@end

@interface Posts

- (NSError*)updatePostsFromUser:(NSString*)user;
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<PostUpdate> delegate;

@end

//ViewController.m:
@implementation ViewController<PostUpdate>

- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    //<...>
    [Posts shared].delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)getLatestsPostButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [[Posts shared] updatePostsFromUser:@"mike"];
}

// protocol PostUpdate
- (void)updateUIWithPosts:(NSArray*)posts FromUser:(NSString*)user
{
    //updating UI with posts
}

@end
```

So here are the questions:

- What else patterns fit the requirements to deliver data from Model to Controllers in non-blocking way?
- What option would you recommend based on your experience, practise or theoretical knowledge?

Comment: I'm not native speaker, so if you are, please tell me about grammar, syntax or any other mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

I recommend going with option-II as it's the most suitable solution in your case.

**Long answer**

First of all, none of the three solutions is wrong, but we are only trying to figure out the best one among them for your case.

• The problem with option-I is that it's always **synchronous** and will block the calling thread while you need it to be **asynchronous**, and therefore, you'll find yourself always calling it from a background thread which means there will be a lot of repeated code that will make maintenance harder (This option can be a good solution if you need the method to be asynchronous sometimes and synchronous most of the time).

• The option-II solves the problem by providing a way to notify the caller thread when the data is ready, and the added parameter isn't really a disadvantage compared to the easiness of use and flexibility it gives. And if you think you will not really need the added parameter in some cases, you can simply make another synchronous version of the method without that parameter:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchPostsForUser:(NSString*)user; /// Synchronous
- (void)fetchPostsForUser:(NSString*)user       /// Asynchronous
               completion:(CompletionHandler)completion;
```

`CompletionHandler` is defined as following:

```
typedef void (^CompletionHandler)(NSArray *result, NSError *error);
```

• The third option isn't really a good solution for your problem. Delegates should be used to deliver events about the class itself, not to deliver responses to previously called methods. Also, notice than you can only have one delegate and this means you can't call such method from two different controllers at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is bad for the reason you mention.

Option 3 is bad because you may have network data returned in a different order than requested if you have 2 network requests going at the same time.  This may make it more difficult than necessary to update your UI properly, depending on your data.  (For example, items could appear out of order.)

Option 2 seems ideal.  It has the benefits of Option 3, plus you get the scope-capturing benefit of Objective-C blocks.  You may want to look at the networking library [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/), which approximately follows this pattern.  One additional consideration is that you should keep your data networking & serialization in a separate class from data persistence / processing.  For example, one class should download data, turn it into an array of `Post` objects, and send it to the callback block.  That callback block could be a view controller, or it could be a separate class that caches the data to disk (using NSCoder or Core Data, for example.)  This approach will keep your code as flexible as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, it seems you're quite experienced developer, how would you design such a class in your practice? Would you choose "completion handler" pattern?

Comment: I typically use completion handlers, yes.